# ¿Como llenar un Select desde una tabla en google drive con ID y Descripción?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-apps-script-html-service

Estoy llenando un conjunto de selects o combos, con datos que están en una tabla en google drive, usando el siguiente formato:

```
ID          Description
00-010000   PRESUPUESTO
00-020000   INGRESOS
00-030000   GASTOS
```

Como puedo cargar los datos para que la instrucción:

```
list.append(new Option(conductor[i],conductor[i]));
```

me muestre los datos de la columna **"description"** pero me almacene los datos de la columna "ID"?

"list" es el nombre del elemento select (html) que estoy llenando, "conductor" es la variable (array) que contiene los datos obtenidos de Google spreadsheet, por último "i" es la variable contador con la que navego a través del array.

Comment: ¿Qué son `list`, `conductor` e `i` en esa instrucción? ¿Qué te está generando ahora mismo? ¿Ves algún error en la consola?

Comment: ¿Desde dónde quieres cargar los datos? ¿Cuál es el formato de archivo donde está la tabla? ¿Se trata de un "select" de HTML?

Comment: "list" es el nombre del elemento select (html) que estoy llenando, "conductor" es la variable (array) que contiene los datos obtenidos de google spreadsheet, por ultimo "i" es la variable contador con la que navego a través del array.

Comment: El html ¿dónde se encuentra? ¿En un archivo de un proyecto de Google Apps Script o en otra parte?

Comment: En un archivo de GAS

Answer (score 1):

A continuación un ejemplo de una aplicación web creada usando un "bounded script" a una hoja de cálculo con una única hoja que en A1:B4 incluye los datos indicados en la pregunta:

```
  |      A      |        B      |
--+-------------|---------------|
 1|ID           |Description    | 
 2|00-010000    |PRESUPUESTO    |
 2|00-020000    |INGRESOS       |
 4|00-030000    |GASTOS         |
```

Al ir a la dirección de la aplicación web se mostrará una lista desplegable mostrando las opciones indicadas en A2:B4, usando los valores de la columna A como los valores de las opciones de la lista desplegable y los valores de la columna B como el texto de las opciones.

#### Código.gs

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}

function getListItems(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var range = sheet.getRange('A2:B4');
  var items = range.getValues();
  return items;
}
```

#### index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="selectList">
    </select>
  </body>
  <script>
    function populateList(items){
      var list = document.getElementById("selectList");
      for(var i in items) {
        list.add(new Option(items[i][1], items[i][0]));
       }
     }
     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(populateList).getListItems();
  </script>
</html>
```

Referencias

- [HTML Service: Create and Serve HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/)